# Android - Counting the value of edittext plus one and displaying it

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I am trying to pass data from one activity to another.
When I retrieve the data out of my created bundle, it returns null instead of the number it should be.

Here is my code where I define the number and pass it on to my new activity:

```
public class SelectDrinks extends MainActivity {
    int AddOneBeer;
    int SubstractOneBeer;
    String AmountOfHoursString;
    String AmountOfBeersString;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.selectdrinks);

        final ImageButton btnBack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnBack);
        final Button btnConfirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSelectedDrinksConfirm);
        final TextView AmountOfHours = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDurationCalc);
        final TextView AmountOfBeers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvAmountOfBeers);
        ImageView plusBeers = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.btnDrink1);
        ImageButton minBeers = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.minBeers);


        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent goBackToMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(goBackToMain);
            }
        });

        btnConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent goToStep3 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Calculate.class);
                goToStep3.putExtra("AmountOfHours", AmountOfHoursString);
                goToStep3.putExtra("AmountOfBeers", AmountOfBeersString);
                startActivity(goToStep3);
            }
        });

        plusBeers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AddOneBeer = Integer.parseInt(AmountOfBeers.getText().toString());
                AddOneBeer++;
                AmountOfBeers.setText(Integer.toString(AddOneBeer));
            }
        });

        minBeers.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SubstractOneBeer = Integer.parseInt(AmountOfBeers.getText().toString());
                SubstractOneBeer--;
                AmountOfBeers.setText(Integer.toString(SubstractOneBeer));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Then I try to use my AmountOfBeersString and AmountOfHoursString in my new activity. When launching it, both the numbers say 'null'.

```
public class Calculate extends MainActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.calculate);

        final ImageButton btnBack = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imgBtnBack);
        final Button btnConfirm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCalculateConfirm);
        TextView changeRequest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvEditRequest);
        TextView tvSummaryBeers = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvSummaryBeers);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        String AmountOfHoursString = bundle.getString("AmountOfHoursString");
        String AmountOfBeersString = bundle.getString("AmountOfBeersString");

        tvSummaryBeers.setText("You drank " + AmountOfBeersString + " beer(s) in " + AmountOfHoursString + " hour(s).");

        btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent goBackToMain = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(goBackToMain);
            }
        });

        btnConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent calculate = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Result.class);
                startActivity(calculate);
            }
        });

        changeRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent back = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SelectDrinks.class);
                startActivity(back);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the Text from TextView

```
 goToStep3.putExtra("AmountOfHours", AmountOfHours.getText().toString() );
 goToStep3.putExtra("AmountOfBeers", AmountOfBeers.getText().toString() );
```

`AmountOfHoursString` and `AmountOfHoursString` are strings declared but i don't see them initialized any where.

Also make sure you use the same keys to get the data from bundle

```
 String AmountOfHoursString = bundle.getString("AmountOfHours");
 String AmountOfBeersString = bundle.getString("AmountOfBeers");
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Calculate` activity, change

```
String AmountOfHoursString = bundle.getString("AmountOfHoursString");
String AmountOfBeersString = bundle.getString("AmountOfBeersString");
```

to

```
String AmountOfHoursString = bundle.getString("AmountOfHours");
String AmountOfBeersString = bundle.getString("AmountOfBeers");
```

You were using a different key than the one you used to send the data in the first place.

Comment: It is still returning 'null'

Comment: @MeindertStijfhals where do you get the string from editText??

Comment: @MeindertStijfhals notice that you are not assigning any values to those strings that you are passing. That's why you're getting null.

Comment: I must've removed this while looking to fix it.. This is inside my btnConfirm.setOnClicklistener

Integer.parseInt(AmountOfHours.getText().toString());
Integer.parseInt(AmountOfBeers.getText().toString());

anyways, it is still returning null

Comment: @MohammedAoufZOUAG changing the keys does not work. Op has not initialized the strings and he has to get the strings from edittext

Comment: @Raghunandan he has to change the keys + initialize the strings. I know